# Distribution of ratio of correlated random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, vectors, normal-distribution

Let $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$ be two independent random vectors, with elements distributed as $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}^{2})$ and $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_{\mathbf{y}}^{2})$, respectively.

I need to derive the PDF of the random variable $Z=\frac{\|\mathbf{x}\|^{4}}{\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|^{2}}$.

EDIT: If the PDF is too difficult to obtain, is it at least possible to derive the expected value of $Z$?

Tentative solution:

- I know that vector $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}$ has elements distributed as $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}^{2}+\sigma_{\mathbf{y}}^{2})$, and also that $\| \mathbf{x} \|^{2} \sim \Gamma(N,\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}^{2})$ and $\| \mathbf{w} \|^{2} \sim \Gamma(N,\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}^{2}+\sigma_{\mathbf{y}}^{2})$. Besides, $x_{i}$ and $w_{i}$ (i.e., the elements of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, respectively) should be joint complex normal distributed with correlation coefficient $\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}^{2}}{\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}^{2} + \sigma_{\mathbf{y}}^{2}}}$. And here I get stuck...

Comment: Do you really mean $\|\mathbf x\|^4 $ in the denominator of $Z ?$

Comment: Yes, the 4 is correct. But analyzing the same expression with the 2 could give me some hints (in case you know a solution for this case).

Comment: OK. Looks hard or intricate.  That the 2 $\sigma$s could be unequal is icky.

Comment: If it helps, one of the two sigmas can be 1.

Comment: Instead of the PDF, do you think it's possible to derive at least the expected value?